# postgres - Move record from one table to another(same schema) after 24 hours of insertion

Tags: postgresql

I have a table X and another table Y with same schema. When a record is inserted in X, after 24 hours, it should be moved to Y automatically.
How can I achieve this in postgres?

Comment: I think that is impractical to move one record from one table to another after 24h from insertion. You can have X.expiry_date and filter the rows if current date is above X.expiry_date. Then schedule a job, that when run will check that condition and move the rows to Y. You can schedule a job by using a cron, scheduler, ... or a Postgres extension [like this one](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron/).

Answer (score 3):

Postgres does not have such automation, you have to use external tools. Eg, make a cronjob to run the script which will do that, [smth like](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):
`pslq -d dbname -c "begin; with d as (delete from x where ts < now() - '1 day'::interval returning *) insert into yselect * from d;; end;`"